# Android development: which phones to use

Tags: android

Here is the context: I have to develop an Android application from version 2.2 to 4.0.
I have read that of course it is better to test on many devices, many screen size etc...
I need to test on an "average" mobile, which means not the slowest device, but also not the fastest.

Which strategy to use seems the best:

- buy a Nexus because no overlay from constructor and is Google products (which one fits to my needs?), and use official ROMs to test on different OS version (use emulators for screen size tests)
- buy 2 chinese phones (which are cheaper, and not that bad) with different sreen features and different OS version.

I cannot find recent topics about that. Can you give me some advices? Thanks!

Comment: This question doesn't fit the the stackoverflow format very well. That being said, I'd acquire test devices based on their market share. Last time I checked, the most popular phone was the Galaxy SII. Is there reason to believe that your userbase is different? Are your users early adopters? Are they rich? Are they poor? Then your list of pipular phones might look a little different.

Answer (score 2):

From a high level I think if it by dividing the different device categories into buckets, e.g. 2.x phones, 3.x tablets (can almost ignore this market now), 4.x phones, 4.x 7 inchers, and 4.x tablets.

Then as there's nothing better than hardware buy devices for the bucket sizes you can afford, starting with the largest bucket first. For the rest use the emulators until needs mean it's good to have the device.

Looking at the chart here:-

http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

2.3 phones is your biggest bucket, and you'll get a cheap device of ebay. I use a nexus 1 as my stock 2.x device.

4.x devices is next. Nexus 7 is very good value and is surprisingly good for testing both phone and tablet ui's although you need to adjust your resource settings for this. Or a Nexus 7 and Nexus 4 if you can justify it.

Emulator's are getting better all the time and you can now emulate specific device settings which helps on those bugs for certain devices / screen sizes, but hopefully this is rare.

Hope that helps,

Ryan

Comment: And have you tried ROM installation, to change OS version? I have read that it is not that practical (there somes risks). And for 2.x device, I'm still asking if it worth it to try chinese device. Thanks for the help.